# How limit of multivariable function with scalar inputs are related to vector inputs

Tags: calculus, limits, vector-spaces, vectors

I was watching lectures by professor Herbert gross(from YouTube) on multivariable calculus and he gradually move from introduction of vectors to n-tuples and then multivariable calculus .

And what I understand that there are some properties  of vectors that are followed by vector spaces but not all properties . And  how a multivariable function takes   n-tuple as input and output a scalar function .

And limit in both cases i.e when input of a multivariable scalar function is a vector and when input of same function is n-tuple ,in both cases definition of limit behaves exactly similar.

But how can we prove using vector space properties only that limits definition would be same in both cases ?

Answer (score 0):

We can define multivariable functions, and we can define vector functions (meaning vectors as inputs, not as outputs).

1. A multivariable function in $n$ variables is a function defined on a subset of $X_1\times\dots\times X_n$, where $X_n$ are arbitrary sets.
2. A vector function is a function defined on a subset of a vector space.

Now we can notice a certain overlap between these concepts. Let $X_1=\dots=X_n=\mathbb R$. Let $U\subseteq X_1\times\dots\times X_n=\mathbb R^n$. Then a function defined on $U$ is both a multivariable function, since it's defined on a subset of a Cartesian product, and a vector function, since it's defined on a subset of the vector space $\mathbb R^n$. So in this case, vector functions and multivariable functions are one and the same thing. Whatever we prove for vector functions, we automatically prove for multivariable functions with inputs from a field, since such multivariable functions *are* vector functions.

That said, in analysis it is really for the best to think of them as vector functions, not multivariable functions, since it's the structure of the vector space which allows us to do analysis in the first place. The fact that the functions we consider often happen to be multivariable ones is a nice bit of trivia, but really has no bearing on the theory at all. For instance, the vector space of functions of the form $a\sin x+b\cos x$ is a perfectly fine vector space on which we can do analysis, but it's not a Cartesian product, so functions defined on this space aren't multivariable ones.